# Demostration of relation between Synchronous speed and Line frequency

Tags: induction-motor

In several books the stator magnetic field frequency is related to the line frequency of the stator current using the number of poles (which is the double of the pole pairs) do you have a demonstration of this?
Even a detailed pdf is usefull.
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The speed is determined by the speed of the rotating magnetic fields. That is described for a three-phase motor in the following diagram.

[image]